# Constructor behaving like a method

Tags: java, inheritance, package

I'm new to Java so not really sure if it's an error on my part. My project has two packages within. I'm trying to use an object belonging to a class of package lovo in an object of a class of package j2. The constructor of object belonging to package lovo is now being treated as a method. Why is that?

```
package j2;
import lovo.kulo;

public class J2 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
      {

    kulo kla ;
    kla = new kulo();
    //kla.kulo();
      }
}

package lovo;

public class kulo {
    public void kulo(){
    System.out.print("This is supposed to be a constructor");}

}
```

When i run there is no output, however when i remove the comment and add it as code there is an output. Since it's a constructor shouldn't it print as soon as the object is created?

Comment: We need to see a code example which reproduces the issue you're having. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is not clear.

Comment: What does "being treated like a method" mean?  How do you know it is being treated like a method?  The best way to get answers here is to show us some code (preferably, code that others actually can compile), tell us what you expected your code to do, and tell us what it actually did instead. (Include actual output and/or compiler error messages.)

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a method. To make it a constructor, remove the `void` return type. It'll also be less confusing if you follow Java naming conventions and begin class names (and therefore constructor names) with an uppercase letter.